# Google maps SDK wont run

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am trying to add Google Maps SDK to my project

I added the following frameworks
[image]

I enabled -ObjC in other linker flags  of the build project

I added the GoogleMapsFramework.bundle resources to my project unmarked "copy resources if needed" checkmark

I put my api key (correct one) in app delegate

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MyApiKey"];

then i added this code to one of my viewcontrollers

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    self.map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.map.delegate = self;
    self.map.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = self.map;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = self.map;
}
```

and when i try to run the app, I get

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
  '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x386d4050'
```

Comment: Can you try the more traditional method of making a marker to see if that works ? i.e.   CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];

Comment: your code looks fine, are you sure its this section of your code?

Comment: yes the xcode stops there

Comment: @Chris this is the line that doesnt work:  self.map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

Comment: try removing the delegate, the code that is shown looks fine so I am guessing the crash is the result of some delegate routine.